# Loading Angular js with asset plugin grails

Tags: angularjs, grails

I have downloaded the angular js version 1.20 and I have put the files in my `assets` directory.

And in my `index.gsp` file, I have this code:

```
    <asset:javascript src="angular.min.js" />
    <asset:javascript src="angular-route.js" />
```

But when the page is been loaded I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=%22Hubbub%22&p1=Er…080%2Fkanban-geneva%2Fassets%2Fangular.min.js%3Fcompile%3Dfalse%3A18%3A387)
```

Even though I have adde the `route.js`, why does it still fails?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asset pipeline ideally you should be just adding you main js file in index.jsp like

```
<asset:javascript src="app.js" />
```

And within app.js you should load other js files like

```
//= require angular/angular
//= require angular-route/angular-route
//= require_tree views
//= require_self
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This plugin has worked well for me.
[Grails Angularjs Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/angularjs).

Checkout its [Readme](https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-angularjs/blob/master/README.md) for instructions